# Function changes two states instead of one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why when I change one state, all other changes? How to prevent this? Within a function, I create two states with the `data` received then pass those two states down to the child prop:

**Parent:**

```
...

// getInitialState: foo and bar

...

// An ajax calls this with an array data
// My two states: foo and bar
getData(data){
  this.setState({ foo: data, bar: data });
}

// Render
<Child myFoo={this.state.foo} myBar={this.state.bar} />
```

**Child:**

```
getInitialState(){
  return{
   childFoo: this.props.myFoo,
   childBar: this.props.myBar
  }
},

valueChange(i, e){
 // i is passed in as a number when this function is called.
 // to show how "i" is passed in is not important
 e.preventDefault();
 var obj = this.state.childFoo;
 var num = obj.find(p => i === p.id);

 // This changes both of my states! Why?
 num.unit_amount = e.target.value;
}
```

Could someone explain why `childBar` also changes? I only need to change one then use the other to compare values with.

Comment: the Child example is not really clear, can you semplify it? What is childBar?

Comment: childBar should not be changed, because you set it only in getInitialState. It may change, only if you update it somewhere else, or if do mount-unmount of child component (if you return null or undefined instead of child)

Comment: @Carlo It's clear. `childBar` is the same as `childFoo`. Those two get their data from the parant prop state.

Answer (score 0):

That is because both your `state` properties are referencing the same object, which is `data`.

When you change `this.state.childFoo` you're also changing `this.state.childBar` because both of them are the same thing with `data` from the parent component.

Try copying the `data` object into each of the state properties, instead of referencing it.

Comment: he use props only for component instantiation

Comment: Ah ok. How to "copy" from one component to the other?

Comment: You can use `Object.assign' : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @degr - true, he uses props only for component instantiation, but still, he's passing references to the same object.

Comment: It change nothing. He have two references to one object on component initialization. Then he can do anything with parent component, it will no change state of child component, because he use props only in `getInitialState` (let think that he did not use `this.refs.childComponent.forceUpdate()`). Also he can do something with state inside of child component using setState. But if he do `this.setState({childFoo: {}, childBar: {}})` I have no idea why he ask question. If he do `this.setState({childFoo: {}})` it should change only one reference, not both of them.